# What does ほど mean in these sentences? Also I would like translations for them

Tags: particle-ほど

男の人は息子さんほど大きいケーキを持っていません。

女の人は息子さんほどたくさんのジュースを持っていません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 男の人は息子さんほど大きいケーキを持っていません。
>
> The man's cake is not as big as his son's.

息子さんほど大きいケーキ in this context means "the bigness of the son's cake".

> 女の人は息子さんほどたくさんのジュースを持っていません。
>
> The woman doesn't have a lot of juice like her son does.

息子さんほどたくさんのジュース in this context means "the son's large amount of juice".

The ほど in these sentences indicate the degree/amount/extent of what comes after it. [The Jisho.org entry has a suitable example sentence](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%A8%8B):

> スージーほど上手にピアノをひけるとよいのだが。
>
> I wish I could play piano as well as Susie.

In each sentence a comparison is made between two people, and the one that precedes ほど is the person being compared *to*.